# EPPlus Sort Pivot Table on DataField instead of just RowField

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I have created an Excel Pivot Table in a worksheet using the EPPlus toolkit, version 3.1.  I am able to sort the resulting table on the row field but would like to be able to do it on the Data Fields.  As an example, I downloaded the 3.1 source code from here:

[EEPlus 3.1 Source Code](https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d09aa5eaced9)

which has a unit test called CreatePivotTable().  It contains a 'Data' tab that looks like so:

```
var ws = _pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Item";
ws.Cells["L1"].Value = "Category";
ws.Cells["M1"].Value = "Stock";
ws.Cells["N1"].Value = "Price";
ws.Cells["O1"].Value = "Date for grouping";
...
```

The test then adds 9 pivot tables sheets.  Looking at the first on, the code is this:

```
var pt = wsPivot1.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot1.Cells["A1"], ws.Cells["K1:N11"], "Pivottable1");
pt.GrandTotalCaption = "Total amount";
pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[1]);
pt.RowFields.Add(pt.Fields[0]);
pt.DataFields.Add(pt.Fields[3]);
pt.DataFields.Add(pt.Fields[2]);
pt.DataFields[0].Function = DataFieldFunctions.Product;
pt.DataOnRows = false;
```

As is, there is no sorting.  If I apply a sort to the first field of the main pivot field collection which is also the second of the two row fields it works:

```
pt.Fields[0].Sort = eSortType.Descending;
```

But what if I want to sort on one of the DataFields like so (both pointing to "Price":

```
pt.Fields[2].Sort = eSortType.Descending;
//or
pt.DataFields[0].Field.Sort = eSortType.Ascending;
```

The sorting does not apply.  It works fine if I do it in excel and add it manually.  Also, I use NetOffice on another project and that can do it as well.  Is that not something that EPPLus can do yet?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and found a solution. Hope it helps if anyone is searching for it:)

```
var rowField = pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[rowFieldName]);
// or var rowField = pivotTable.Fields[rowFieldName]; if rowField is already added
var dataField = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields[dataFieldName]);
rowField.SetAutoSort(dataField, eSortType.Ascending);
rowField.Items.Refresh();
```

Reference: https://epplussoftware.com/en/Developers/SortingRangesAndTables